# Can someone explain what is the operator ":?"?

Tags: javascript-objects

Can someone explain what is the operator?

```
 @observable.ref navigationState: ?NavigationState = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's is safe navigation operator", i.e. x?.y.

for refrence [go here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16)

**or take this example**

```
  <md-select placeholder="Select Month" [(ngModel)]="monthSelected" 
  #userSelect>

  <md-option *ngFor="let userSelection of CalanderContent" 
  [value]="userSelection">
  {{ userSelection.month }}
  </md-option>
  </md-select>
  {{userSelect.selected.value.days}} <- Compile time error beacuse we didnt selected
                                          any options at time of initializing.
  {{userSelect.selected?.value?.days}} <- Correct because it waits if its selected 
                                          then , displays the value
```

Comment: but it is :?x not x?.y

Comment: x here is anything which can't give immediate result